# Dynamically loading com.databricks:spark-csv spark package to my application

Tags: apache-spark, spark-csv

I need to load com.csv spark packages dynamically to my application, using spark submit , it works

```
spark-submit --class "DataLoaderApp" --master yarn 
             --deploy-mode client 
             --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.4.0  target/scala-2.10/ra-etl_2.10-1.0.0.jar LOAD GGSN /data-sources/DXE_Ver/1_4/MTN_Abuja/GGSN/20160221/GGSN_0_20160221074731.dat
```

but when I use

```
spark-submit --class "DataLoaderApp" --master yarn 
             --deploy-mode client 
             target/scala-2.10/ra-etl_2.10-1.0.0.jar LOAD GGSN /data-sources/DXE_Ver/1_4/MTN_Abuja/GGSN/20160221/GGSN_0_20160221074731.dat
```

for below configuration it doesn't work...

```
val conf = new SparkConf()
                .setAppName("Data Loader Application")
                .set("spark.jar.packages","com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.4.0")
```

Comment: Can you pls confirm that you are using Scala 2.10, while you link to ``spark-csv_2.11``? Also, which Spark version are you using?

Comment: yes, I use spark 1.6

Answer (score 0):

Using `spark-csv` via `SparkConf` seems to be still an [open issue](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv/issues/178). Nevertheless, if your purpose is to save the need for typing the `--packages` argument every time you call `spark-submit`, you can add the relevant dependencies in your `spark-defaults.conf` file (normally located in your `$SPARK_HOME/conf` directory) as follows:

1. Locate the paths of `spark-csv_2.11-1.4.0.jar` and its dependencies, `commons-csv-1.1.jar` and `univocity-parsers-1.5.1.jar`. These should be already present in your system if you have already used `spark-csv` once; in my case (user `ctsats`), these paths are:

   ```
   /home/ctsats/.ivy2/cache/com.databricks/spark-csv_2.11/jars/spark-csv_2.11-1.4.0.jar
   /home/ctsats/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.commons/commons-csv/jars/commons-csv-1.1.jar
   /home/ctsats/.ivy2/cache/com.univocity/univocity-parsers/jars/univocity-parsers-1.5.1.jar
   ```
2. Open `spark-defaults.conf` file (in `$SPARK_HOME/conf` – create it if does not exist), and add the above paths with the argument `spark.driver.extraClassPath`, i.e. if your paths are like above, then add the following line:

   ```
   spark.driver.extraClassPath /home/ctsats/.ivy2/cache/com.databricks/spark-csv_2.11/jars/spark-csv_2.11-1.4.0.jar:/home/ctsats/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.commons/commons-csv/jars/commons-csv-1.1.jar:/home/ctsats/.ivy2/cache/com.univocity/univocity-parsers/jars/univocity-parsers-1.5.1.jar
   ```

Now, the `spark-csv` package will be automatically loaded whenever you call `spark-submit` or `spark-shell`.